# Need help with inverter

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, voltage-regulator, inverter

I am wondering if it is possible too hook up an oxygen concentrator in my car for longer than normal trips. My gf needs 10 to 15 liters but can maybe get away with 10 (1 machine) for a drive. The machine is 120volts almost 600 watts ( i believe it says 4.5A) and I usually run two machines in the house but for a drive for about 4 hours i can get away with 1 machine but don't have enough portable oxygen. Do you think i can add an inverter and batteries in my trunk to run the machine? if so i would need advice on installing it.
Thanks

Comment: They have off the shelf inverters that plug into your cig. lighter at Wal-Mart and other places, for under 100.00, that can handle that kind of load.

Comment: @TimSpriggs - incorrect. 4.5A @ 120V through an inverter is over 45 amps from 12 volts! That'll melt a cig. lighter jack, if it didn't blow the fuse first!

Comment: You may be right but they do make some powerful inverters these days.   so you can take the chance of blowing a fuse or catching everything on fire from the home brew device that you make.  And  remember , oxygen is an accellerant.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/BESTEK-Inverter-Automotive-Refrigerator-Microwave/dp/B00T93K9KU/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1460638055&sr=8-10&keywords=car+dc+to+ac+power+inverter

Answer (score 1):

Boost converter is your friend
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter

Also have you thought about actually making pure oxygen? You could hook up a water electrolyzer to the existing 12v wiring and just vent the hydrogen or even better turn the hydrogen back into water from low concentration atmospheric oxygen and put it back into the electrolyzer. Such setup could be even more efficient than the machine you have.

Answer (score 0):

600 W is considered a high load for a 12 V car electrical system but may be do-able with additional batteries.

From our power formula \$ P = VI \$ we can calculate that the current required at any voltage is given by \$ I = \frac {P}{V} \$ so for 120 V mains the current required is \$ I = \frac {600W}{120V} = 5~A \$ which is reasonable but to run the same motor from a 12 V battery would give \$ I = \frac {600W}{12V} = 50~A \$. To give an idea, your headlamps probably use 55 W bulbs, giving a 110 W load and current of \$ I = \frac {110W}{12V} \approx 10~A \$.

The situation is even worse when you add in the inverter losses at, say, 20%.

> Do you think i can add an inverter and batteries in my trunk to run the machine?

Battery capacity required would be \$ \frac {50A \cdot 4h}{80\%} = 250~Ah \$ capacity.

It is do-able but a lot of work and some safety concerns with batteries, acid, high current cables, etc., which would all need to be secured. I'd look again at the oxygen cylinder option.